# I have a weird shadow / occlusion glitch in my animation with Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shadows

I have a weird "1 frame" glitch in my animation causing an unwanted occlusion or shadow.
You can see it in my gif in the mouth, and behind the creature a shadow trail on the picture.

[image]

- Motion blur is activated
- The creature is in a principled volumetric cube
- Depth of field is activated
- Default sampling and render settings
- No light animation

[image]

It's not the first time I have this issue